# URL rewriting gives 500 Internal server error

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My second URL redirection fails, server giving 500 Internal Server Error when I hit the URL : `example.com/services/SV0087`, but the first redirection works : `example.com/items/I5402`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

AddType text/x-component .htc

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

####### this works seamlessly
RewriteRule ^items/([^/]*)$ /items/index.asp?itemcode=$1 [L]
```

**-   this gives 500 internal server error**

```
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)$ /services/index.asp?servicecode=$1 [L]
```

**-   it receives the value as index.asp when i do $_GET['servicecode']**

```
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)$ services/index.asp?servicecode=$1 [L]
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the RewriteRule; the error is much more likely to be in `services\index.asp`

Comment: @Nick : I found the issue, in my servicecode parameter, it receive the value as index.asp when i do $_GET['servicecode']

Comment: @Nick - dear sir, when i remove the slash before "services" then only it works, on adding the slash it goes to 500 error

Comment: @Nick : dear sir please check out my update in post

Answer (score 0):

I had to write the complete **condition code** separately for both URLs, then it worked :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteRule ^items/([^/]*)$ /items/index.asp?itemcode=$1 [L] 




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)$ /services/index.asp?servicecode=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Because otherwise the directive would have executed unconditionally and resulted in a rewrite loop. `/services/index.asp` is also matched by `^services/([^/]*)$`. You could also have resolved it by using a more restrictive regex, perhaps `([^./]*)`. Or one that specifically matches the _servicecode_. (Because of how the code is split in your question, it's not actually clear that the `^services` directive actually follows the preceding directives in-place.)